# How to send text messages to non apple devices from an iPad?

Tags: ipad, messages, sms

i just bought my iPad mini for 2 weeks or more which has been jail broken. So since I'm using a weekly prepaid data plan, I need to renew the data plan again and again for every week. Hence I wanna know if I can use iMessages in order to apply my data plan again which I need to send it to '28882'.

Is that possible to use iMessages, or if it does not allow me to do so, do you have any idea how to send text messages as if 'normal messages' to especially non-apple devices?

Any idea what other apps do I need to use?

Comment: Did you try to send an SMS to a friend with a non-Apple phone?

Comment: Yup, i did, most of my friends are android user samsung, HTC etc. and i dont know how to get whatsapp on my ipad mini. :/

Comment: If sending SMS to others works, I would guess that sending SMS to 28882 should work as well. Or ask your provider, you won't be the only iPad user with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Up until I did an update, I could email non Apple users without any problem. After the update, I couldn't. I spent over an hour with an Apple "genius" that finally fixed it. I just updated again and I have the same problem. This is ridiculous! I have customers that text me orders. I am so frustrated!! This is messing with my income!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have a different question, ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can also add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to get more users interested in the question. You can also read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances on getting a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Settings->Messages there is an option Send as SMS

If this still not working, you can disable iMessage in the same settings page.

Comment: in what settings? nevermind.  I was thinking of an iMac, not ios device. Sorry.